# Jquery line break replace with br tag isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jQuery with `\n` to be replaced with `<br />` tag.

```
var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data)
var test = msg.message;
test.replace(/\n/, "<br />");
//OR
test.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
//OR
test.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");

alert(test);
```

I am unable to get linebreak. I tried all of them but failed. I think  string ***test*** is not going through ***replace function***.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return value to the variable, **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**  will not update the variable

```js
var test = "good\nmorning";
test = test.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
//--^^^----- update variable `test` with returned value
alert(test);
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and also not working..

Comment: @tashi : run the code snippet

Comment: @tashi : can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X6fjY/

Comment: It behaves different in here. Even without going replace function. It will already broken when I do alert.

Comment: @tashi: Your example does not even try to replace line breaks. It does something completely different.

Comment: I forgot to mention, test is just converted with JSON.

Comment: @tashi: We can't help if you don't provide an actual, complete example. Again, your jsFiddle example has nothing to do what you asked in the question, and the issue in the code example in the question is addressed by this answer. If that doesn't help you, then you have a different problem or different code.

Comment: var test string is coming from JSON. like ***var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data)
var test = msg.message;***.

Answer (score 1):

except last one, all of them working.

```js
    var test = "good\nmorning";
    test1  = test.replace(/\n/, "<br />");

    console.log(test1);
    //OR
    test2 = test.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
     console.log(test2);    
    //OR
    test3  = test.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
    console.log(test3);
```

Comment: The last one (`test  = test.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");`) is incorrect btw.

Comment: All of them not working for me.

Comment: this is just copy of his code :)

Comment: @Omidam81 What is the point of doing that?

Comment: @ian-kemp, i just want to show the correct method of using javascript replace, it not about regular expression and other things.